# <classes> element flipping in and out of existence in storyboard file

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios5, xcode4.2

This isn't a big problem but it is annoying. Every time I edit my storyboard in Interface Builder and I want to check it into the revision control system there's a  element that is either generated or removed: if it existed it is removed and vice versa.

It adds needless noise to my checkins.

Does someone have an idea of what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: +1 here. Is it a matter of having different Xcode versions among team members?

Comment: I was the only developer at the time.

Comment: hmm... even weirder... i'm surprised this question has only been visited 50 times over a year: it's a surprising behavior!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313728/why-does-git-addremove-the-storyboard-classes-section-repeatedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to Xcode 5 as soon as this becomes feasible. There they change the XIB format to be mergeable XML.

While you are still on Xcode 4.x you need to ignore changes to XIB files. Don't always commit all, but revert those changes that you don't want as "noise"